# 4D's Development Methodology

Tags: methodology

Anybody out there heard of "Define Design Develop Deploy" ? Just curious if someone knows or uses this development methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it seemed more like a marketing thing to me.  It's a cute way to package the software development steps.

Answer (score 3):

It is called a "Waterfall" methodology and as such it is a bit antiquated (early 90's).

Comment: I thought so too, just wanted to get a feel for what people are using.